# Kronecker product in Python and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I was trying to reproduce a result in Python from MATLAB. However, I can't seem to get it right. This is the correct MATLAB code:

```
nx = 5;
ny = 7;

x = linspace(0, 1, nx); dx = x(2) - x(1);
y = linspace(0, 1, ny); dy = y(2) - y(1);

onex = ones(nx, 1);
oney = ones(ny, 1);

Dx = spdiags([onex -2*onex onex], [-1 0 1], nx, nx);
Dy = spdiags([oney -2*oney oney], [-1 0 1], ny, ny);

Ix = eye(nx); Iy = eye(ny);
L = kron(Iy, Dx);

size(L) % 35   35
```

Now, this is the Python code:

```
nx = 5
ny = 7
x = linspace(0, 1, nx); dx = x[1] - x[0]
y = linspace(0, 1, ny); dy = y[1] - y[0]

onex = ones(nx)
oney = ones(ny)
Dx = sparse.dia_matrix( ([onex, -2*onex, onex], [-1,0,1] ), shape=(nx,nx))
Dy = sparse.dia_matrix( ([oney, -2*oney, oney], [-1,0,1] ), shape=(ny,ny))

Ix = eye(nx)
Iy = eye(ny)

L = kron(Iy, Dx)

L.shape # (7, 7)
```

As far I have been able to verify, everything is correct until the definition of L. According to MATLAB `kron(Iy, Dx)` (which is supposed to be the kronecker product) should produce a 35X35 matrix, but Python thinks it should be a 7X7 matrix. In simpler calculations, both give the correct answer:

Python:

```
kron(array(([1,2],[2,3])), [1,2])

array([[1, 2, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 3, 6]])
```

MATLAB

```
kron([1 2; 2 3], [1 2]) 

ans = 1   2   2   4
      2   4   3   6
```

Why do I get different results?

Thanks!

Comment: Wild guess: do things behave better if you use `Dx.todense()` or `Dx.toarray()` (and the same for `Dy`?)

Comment: Exactly right. Minutes ago I was trying to construct the matrix I used without scipy.sparse. Do you know a workaround when using sparse matrices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`sparse.kron`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.kron.html) for the Kronecker product of sparse matrices.

[`numpy.kron`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) does not handle sparse matrices.  When given sparse matrices, it might not generate an error, but the value it returns will not be correct.