# Kronecker product for large matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I am looking for an effficient way of computing the Kronecker product of two large matrices. I have tried using the method `kronecker()` as follows:

```
 I = diag(700)
 data = replicate(15, rnorm(120))
 test = kronecker(I,data)
```

However, it takes a long time to execute and then gives the following error:

```
 Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.8 Gb
```

Comment: Well, you are trying to create a matrix with nearly a billion entries there. It's not a matter of "efficiency" -- although if you know one of your matrices is diagonal, the KroneckerProduct will be spectacularly sparse.   Maybe do it piece-by-piece?  The Kronecker Product can easily be "subdivided" .

Comment: Probably the above comment should be posted as answer since unless you have a machine with loads of memory you won't execute this.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I realize that the outcome is of dimension (84000,10500), but it is a must for me to compute that Kronecker product. Could you please detail what you mean by "subdivided"? Or would parallel computing be of help here? Thanks

Comment: This may give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035767/kronecker-product-in-python-and-matlab

Comment: Do you really need the matrix (an array of coefficients), or do you just need to be able to do some computations with it (multiplying by it, solving linear systems, computing eigenvalues, etc.)? If you really need the matrix, since it is block-diagonal, you can use `bdiag` in the `Matrix` package to only store the non-zero coefficients.

Comment: Actually, I need it as part of a computation. But I like your idea of `bdiag`. Thanks.

Comment: Even if you need to compute with the matrix, you probably can vectorize or create a loop operation which only requires a small subset of your matrix for each calculation.  Again, if you can describe your actual **problem**, not how you are trying to solve it, we can help more. (to paraphrase the R-DataMungerGuru)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As long as you use `Matrix::Diagonal` to construct your diagonal matrix, you'll automatically get your `test` object constructed as a sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
I=Diagonal(700)
data = replicate(15,rnorm(120))
system.time(test <- kronecker(I,data))
##   user  system elapsed
##  0.600   0.044   0.671 
dim(test)
## [1] 84000 10500
format(object.size(test),"Mb")
## [1] "19.2 Mb"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are computing `kron(I,A)*v` where `v` is a vector you can do this using `vec(A*V)` where `V` reshapes `v` into a matrix. This uses the more general rule that `vec(ABC)=kron(C',A)*vec(B)`. This avoids forming the Kronecker product and uses far less operations to perform the computation.

Note that `V` may need to be transposed depending on how matrix storage is handled (columns versus rows).