# Efficiently compute the product of kronecker product and diagonal matrices

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have two dense matrices `A` and `B` of dimension 252 and 308. `C` is a diagonal matrix with elements 1s and 0s.

I want to calculate `C(A \otimes B)C`. If I calculate

```
C %*% (A %x% B) %*% C
```

I get `cannot allocate vector of size 44.9 Gb`. Is there an efficient way to calculate this matrix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kronecker product for large matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850576/kronecker-product-for-large-matrices)

Comment: @Jan No. Because A and B are dense matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are able to solve the issue since you will be stuck at `(A %x% B)` if you have both `A` and `B` as ***dense matrices***.

With the given dimensions for `A` and `B`, you will have `(m*n)^2 = 6024243456` elements in `A %*% B`, and this number exceeds the upper limit (see the [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9984368/12158757))

Answer (score 0):

If `C` is diagonal with diagonal entries equal to 0 or 1, then

```
C %*% (A %x% B) %*% C
```

can be represented compactly as

```
(A %x% B)[i, i]
```

where `i = which(as.logical(diag(C)))`.  That is, you only need to store a principal submatrix of the Kronecker product.  But without knowing anything about the nonzero pattern of `i`, it is impossible to advise on how to construct that submatrix efficiently ...

Comment: The elements of C has consecutive 1s and 0s.