# how to repeat a numpy vector to create an array with the rest of array being zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like the create the following numpy array, based on the following vector
`e = numpy.array([1,0,0,0,0,0])`

```
a = [ [e, 0, ---, 0],
      [0, e, ---, 0],
      -
      -
      [0, 0, ---, e]]
```

(Note: The `0` in this array is thus a zero vector and not scalar)

and thus;

```
a = [ [1,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0, ---, 0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0,0, ---, 0,0,0,0,0,0],
      -
      -
      [0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0  ---, 1,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

The solutions does not have to make use of `e`. The structure of the first array (based on `e`) is due the underlying linear algebra of the problem I'm tackling.

I have looked at tile and repeat from numpy. However, I was not able to create `a` with these functions. Ideally, I would like to use a numpy function as speed is quite important for my implementation.

---

EDIT: `e` is an numpy array and not a python list

EDIT: added some extra information

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? You'll end up with different data types in your array - this will definitely be an issue with efficiency.

Comment: Use a couple `for` loops?

Comment: @rammelmueller you mean because  `e` is an list? Good point; `e` is an numpy array as well -> edited

Comment: @Julien ideally, I would avoid python for loops for computational speed

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,k->ijk',np.eye(len(e), dtype='int'), e).reshape(len(e),-1)`, the shape is still ambiguous.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thank you; I ended up using your suggestion. Great to learn something new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the suggestion from 'Michael Szczesny', was the one I ended up using. However, I found out as well that the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) is the mathematical operation which I was looking for.

From this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17039049/12767361) it seems(/seemed) that the SciPy implementation works better than the NumPy one. This answer is quite old (2013). However, I do not have enough reputation to ask a followup question.

Maybe someone else would benefit from this information

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a solution with a single `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np

# Define the sizes of the array.
a, b = 4, 6

matrix = np.zeros(shape=(a*b,b), dtype=int)
for i in range(b):
    matrix[i*a,i] = 1
print(matrix.T)
```